# How To Display created_at Date As Min/Day Ago Format Using Carbon on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am using `{{ date('jS M, Y', strtotime($row->created_date)) }}`
 and result like 4th Sep, 2017 format I want to display created date as 6 min ago/  1 day ago/ 1 week ago format. How can i do?

Answer (score 6):

If `created_date` is an instance of `Carbon\Carbon`, you can do:

```
$row->created_date->diffForHumans()
```

If it isn't an instance of Carbon, you can do:

```
(new Carbon\Carbon($row->created_date))->diffForHumans()
```

I dont know what format `created_date` is, so you might want to read the Carbon docs on instantiating a new instance of Carbon for your format http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Answer (score 0):

To cast a field not named created_at or updated_at to carbon you need to [register it on the model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) first, then you can use `->diffForHumans()` on it